# Using ROS to detect obstacles

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to using ROS, I am currently doing my final year project for detecting obstacles in an outdoor environment (e.g on airport runway surfaces). Are there any tips on how I can construct a package that can perform 3d mapping of obstacles using stereo vision? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239999/using-ros-to-detect-obstacles/) by [Zack29](https://answers.ros.org/users/27557/zack29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glagla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27526/glagla/) on 2016-07-21**:
Looking for the same thing basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several existing ROS packages that process stereo camera data. You might browse packages for your ROS installation: http://www.ros.org/browse/list.php. In particular, the `stereo_image_proc` package claims to be able to publish point clouds from stereo image processing (http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). (I don't have any experience with that package, so can't give any more info.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [glagla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27526/glagla/) on 2016-08-03**:
The problem appears with ROS KINETIC as in INDIGO it works fine, but this is not the case of KINETIC which provide no disparity map

**Comment by [Zack29](https://answers.ros.org/users/27557/zack29/) on 2016-08-08**:
I installed ROS INDIGO and I seem to face the same problem as using ROS KINETIC, following the 'Choosing good stereo parameters' tutorial, I got till this part:
$ rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
reconfigure_gui started
and the gui shows a blank drop down menu. I have no idea how to proceed.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-08**:
Unfortunately, as I said, I don't have experience with those packages. If you like, I'll delete this answer entirely to avoid people bypassing the question because they think it's already answered.

**Comment by [Zack29](https://answers.ros.org/users/27557/zack29/) on 2016-08-09**:
Thanks for the offer, I think it's alright to leave the answer up, it is a good starting point for people who want to do the same thing as I did. Maybe they would have more knowledge on how to work around the errors.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-09**:
Stupid question, probably, but have you started `roscore` and the stereo processing node first? (I haven't yet used dynamic reconfiguration, but it looks like `rqt_configure` just looks at the current node graph to determine what to show in its GUI.)

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-09**:
Also, you don't have to run `rqt_configure`, probably. Instead, set parameters in your launch file, then kill, edit, and restart to try different parameters. More of a pain, of course.